# Show values instead of id's sqlite

Tags: c#, database, sqlite

I have database with tables **user** and **department**. Fields in **user** table are: id, login, pwd, editdate. In department table the field are id, description, user_id, editdate.
The relation is: Relation only in VisualStudio.

You can see screenshot here:
[image: http://i.imgur.com/3oRXSiN.png]

So, i have dataGridView at form, which is binded to **department** table.

Screen of the form with dataGridView (in Russian): 
[image: http://i.imgur.com/4urti4l.png] .

I want to see value from user table instead of ID 1 in "Автор записи" column.
The some code:

```
    private void CatalogForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        departmentTableAdapter.Fill(dataDataSet.department);
        userTableAdapter.Fill(dataDataSet.user);
    }

    private void DepartmentCatalogView()
    {
        catalogGridView.DataSource = departmentBindingSource;
        Text = @"Подразделения";
        catalogGridView.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        catalogGridView.Columns[0].Visible = false;
        catalogGridView.Columns[1].HeaderText = @"Подразделение";
        catalogGridView.Columns[2].HeaderText = @"Автор записи";
        catalogGridView.Columns[3].HeaderText = @"Дата записи";
    }
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I want to see value from user table login column instead of ID 1 in "Автор записи" column. How to do this?

Comment: You need to change the binding source's query (which you have not shown).

Comment: Yes, i use standart query in bindingSource: SELECT * FROM department.

Comment: Should i use this one: SELECT * FROM department LEFT JOIN user ON department.user_id = user.id ?